# Windmill generator voltage-regulation with clamping diode

Tags: voltage-regulator, diodes, generator

I am making a windmill powered generator. The charge controller I have is rated for a maximum input of 15V. I want to protect the controller in the event of high voltage spikes produced in a wind storm (50 V max from generator motor, for example).

I am wondering if/how I can use an avalanche (clamping) diode to shunt excess voltage away from the controller, to ground. Under normal circumstances, the charge controller will charge a 12V battery bank.

The general schematic is attached. The exact parts could be:
[Avalanche diode](http://www.ebay.com/itm/161153255171?_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK:MEBIDX:IT)
[Resistor](http://www.ebay.com/itm/150471590412?_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2648&ssPageName=STRK:MEBIDX:IT)

Note: Since the diode is rated for 5W peak continous, at 50V I think I may actually need 500 ohms resistance although the picture shows 200.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: your ebay liks do not work.

Comment: I'm glad you decided to ask this question here... but you still have your diode pointed backwards. I told you that in my Instructables comment! Also, those series resistors will have a voltage drop, so they can't be there in this case. Also, I mentioned that the shunt regulator design was pretty inefficient, so it wouldn't be a good idea for this kind of high power circuit. It is just useful when you have limited time, board space, or budget.

Comment: Oopsies. Well I am leaning towards buck regulator now. Thanks for guiding me to this resource.

Answer (score 3):

Use a buck regulator in front of the charge controller. You can find ones that are rated in excess of 50v and they should be 90%+ efficient meaning you  can harvest the energy rather than dump it into a zener and resistor.

Regarding your circuit, you have the zener diode the wrong way round.

Comment: I agree with Andy.  One caveat: does your charge controller function when the input voltage is lower than the batteries?  Some do, some don't.  If not, then use a buck-boost regulator instead of a buck.  That way you can still harvest power when the winds are slow.

Comment: Even with the Zener diode the right way around, the circuit will not limit the voltage to the charge cvontroller to 15 volts, as there will be a voltage drop across the resistors that are in series with the Zener.

Comment: The specs for the controller I have are: 
battery rated voltage: 12v
wind turbine rated power: 300w
wind turbine braked voltage: 15v
recover voltage: 13.5v
quiescent dissipation: <8ma
pretection grade:IP67

Does the braked voltage mean that the controller will be protected from voltages above that value?
It was all originally in Chinese and I just received the translation.

Comment: @user3239034 I didn't request the turbine specs so how about adding them to your question in case others find them relevant.

Comment: It was a treadmil motor at one point. It is a DC permement magnet motor rated for 130V 18A at 6700 RPM. Model B4CPM-102T.

Comment: read my previous comment.